# Geany doesn't execute scripts in Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, python, geany

When I try to execute a program in Geany it opens a terminal window and goes to the file's parent directory but does not execute my program.

For example the terminal opens in the /pythonEx directory but doesn't run `if.py` file. The script runs fine if I call it directly.

[image: my terminal screen]

Comment: Your question is unclear, you should describe it more clearly so we can help you.

Comment: what should I add for description? there is no error in terminal when I use F5 to execute. I can run my python file in terminal directly but when I use F5 it just opens terminal window and it is in my file directory. I think it cant type or run "python if.py" in this window

Comment: Got it... can you provide some information about the location of file and script itself?

Comment: my file is in home/vahid/pythonEx/if.py

Comment: What version of geany you are running?

Comment: I use Geany version 1.29

Comment: So you are running zesty... have you tried other scripts? a simple bash script for example. Right now I can't produces your situation on my system. I'll try later and let you know if I came up with anything.

Comment: I dont know what is simple bash script but I tried common "hello word" and didnt work so

Comment: Add more details to your question please. Exactly how were you trying to execute the script

Comment: I try to execute by pressing F5 key. then terminal window opens and it is in my file directory `/pythonEx` as you can see in screenshot but nothing happens!  I saw building menu settings and every thing seems good there. in execute text box is : `python "%f"`

Comment: it can't be geany's python configuration, cause you are not able to run bash scripts too.

Comment: so what should I do ???!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I couldn't execute my program in new opened terminal window but by changing Geany preferences it can execute python script in its terminal (bellow the editor window)

so Open the **Edit -> Preferences** go to **terminal** tab and check two last items:

- Execute programs in the VTE
- Don't use run script